# How do I un-install a specific open jdk 1.8.0_322 which I suspect was installed using homebrew. All my trials have failed

Tags: java, java-8, homebrew, homebrew-cask, sdkman

I need to un install my JDK 1.8 version from my Mac 12.2.1 Montere. However much I try I could not get rid of it.

**When I run** `$ java -version`, I get

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_322"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-8.322.06.1 (build 1.8.0_322-b06)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-8.322.06.1 (build 25.322-b06, mixed mode)
```

**When I run** `$ which java`, I get

```
/usr/bin/java
```

**When I run** `$ /usr/bin/java -version`, I get

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_322"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-8.322.06.1 (build 1.8.0_322-b06)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-8.322.06.1 (build 25.322-b06, mixed mode)
```

**When I run** `$ ls -l /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/` , I get

```
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  98 Feb  4 11:10 package-lock.json
```

**When I run** `$ sudo rm -rf /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_322.jdk`

I get to nothing, except being asked for password

I want to manage my Java/JDK installation, management etc. with **SDKMAN** alone. With **homebrew** and **sdkman** it is getting confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Following the docs => https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/install/installation-jdk-and-jre-macos.htm#JSJIG-GUID-F9183C70-2E96-40F4-9104-F3814A5A331F

**Note:**

> Do not attempt to uninstall Java by removing the Java tools from
> /usr/bin. This directory is part of the system software and any
> changes will be reset by Apple the next time that you perform an
> update of the OS.

1. In your Terminal go to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines.

*If the folder does not exists, it can be at higher directory before "/Users"*

2. Remove the directory whose name matches the following format by executing the `rm` command as a root user or by using the `sudo` tool

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/(your jdk1.8.0_322.jdk folder)
For example, once inside of JavaVirtualMachines, run:

```
$ rm -rf jdk1.8.0_322.jdk
```

Comment: If the error persist, try restart your terminal and if persist yet, try open your .bashrc or .zshrc to exclude some line if it has any export with that openjdk. Let me know if my answer fir the question plz =)